# Convertir string en nominal en Weka

Tags: php, string

Tengo un `.arff` con unos datos que tienen tres atributos string y luego uno numérico que es la clase. Cuando intento realizar el modelo para después predecir la clase de otros datos, no me deja indica:

`Cannot handle string attributes!`

Ya probé a realizar el filtro `StringToNominal` para *parsear* los datos string a un número, pero sigue sin funcionar. También probé con el filtro `StringToWordVector`, aunque esta vez me crea el modelo, luego cuando lo uso para predecir me indica que los datos son de la clase 0 o 1.

¿Cómo puedo traducir los atributos string en nominales?